# Induced Map - Correct way to prove function is well-defined

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, quotient-spaces

Suppose $T \in L(V,W)$. Define $\tilde{T}: V/\ker(T) \to W$ by $\tilde{T}(\vec v + \ker(T)) = T(\vec v)$.

I am unsure as to how to show this mapping is well defined. I understand that the basic principle is to show that each X value maps to only 1 Y value but I am confused how this would work for quotient spaces as the X input.

Any help please?

Comment: This *wouldn't* be well defined for most $T$. Do we have $T^2=0$?

Comment: @MattSamuel I'm sorry I mistyped the definition, it should map to a vector space W. I believe this makes it well-defined but I am not sure as to how to prove this.

Comment: You need to take two vectors in the same equivalence class. I.e., a v and w such that their difference is in the kernel of T and then show their image under $\tilde{T}$ is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Given the edit, just taken any element $\vec k\in \ker(T)$ to get $$T(\vec v+\vec k) = T(\vec v)+T(\vec k) = T(\vec v).$$
This does not depend on our choice of $\vec k\in \ker(T)$. This is what makes it well defined; it takes the same value on the whole equivalence class $\vec v+\ker(T)$.

The point is that we apply $T$ to $\vec v+\vec k$, which is a different member of the equivalence class, we get the same value, so it makes sense to say that the value of the function $\tilde T$ on the equivalence class is equal to $T(\vec v)$, where $\vec v$ is any element in the equivalence class.

Comment: The first part $T(\vec v + \vec k)$ should be $\tilde{T}(\vec v + \vec k)$ right? Since I want to prove $\tilde{T}$ is well-defined

Comment: @learning_maniac No, you can't apply $\tilde T$ to an element of $V$, only to an element of the form $\vec v+kernel(T)$.

Comment: @learning_maniac I expanded a bit.

Comment: Thank you so much that made it very clear to understand! Just a follow up question, how would I show that $range(T) = range(\tilde{T})$? Is going by the definition of the mapping not good enough reasoning as $\tilde{T} = T(\vec v)$, wouldn't that imply that $range(T) = range(\tilde{T})$?

Comment: @learn Pick an element in the range of $T$ and show that you can hit it with $\tilde T$, and vice versa.

Comment: So if I'm not wrong, something like: pick $\vec w \in range(T)$. Then $\vec w = T(\vec v)$ where $v \in V$ which implies $\vec w = \tilde{T}(\vec v + ker(T))$. And then you would also show the other direction. Would I be correct in saying this is how to prove it?

Comment: @learn Yes that's right.

Comment: cool thank you so much for you help, I appreciate it a bunch!

Comment: @learn No problem.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment, the usual strategy when showing that maps from a quotient are well defined, is to show that it is constant on equivalence classes. Another way of phrasing this is to say that the map is "independent of representative". So, we need to take two representatives from the same equivalence class $v + \ker{T} = w + \ker{T}$ and show that $\tilde{T}(v + \ker{T}) = \tilde{T}(w + \ker{T})$.

Ok so now that we have the strategy, lets apply it. Since $v + \ker{T} = w + \ker{T}$, it then follows that $v - w \in \ker{T}$. That is, $0 = T(v-w) = T(v) - T(w) \implies T(v) = T(w)$ where the last equality follows from $T$ being a linear map.

Now, let us send $v + \ker{T}$ and $w + \ker{T}$ through the map $\tilde{T}$.
$$\tilde{T}(v + \ker{T}) = T(v)$$
$$\tilde{T}(w + \ker{T}) = T(w)$$
But by the previous paragraph, we know that $T(v) = T(w)$ and we are done.

Comment: Sorry for another question, do you know how I would go about showing $V/kernel(T)$ is isomorphic to $range(T)$?

Comment: This is a classic result commonly called “the first isomorphism theorem”. Check out google and in particular wikipedia

Comment: I've tried reading up on wikipedia and also several youtube videos but I am still unable to understand how that isomorphism works, is there any simple way to try and prove or show this theorem?

Comment: You need to show that your map $\tilde{T}$ is an isomorphism. This amount to showing that it is a linear map, injective (one to one), and surjective (onto).

Comment: Ok maybe I misunderstood what to show then cause I have proved linear map, injective, and surjective. I just thought that only shows that it is isomorphic but I thought you needed to show something else to show it is isomorphic to range(T). So there is nothing else you have to prove to show it is isomorphic to range(T)?

Comment: The map $\tilde{T}$ has domain $V/ \ker T$ and range $range (\tilde{T})$. Once you show that $\tilde{T}$ is an isomorphism (that is, show that it is linear, 1-1, and onto), you will have successfully shown that $V/ \ker T$ is isomorphic to $range(\tilde{T})$. I see on the comments of Matt Samuel's answer that you have already shown that $range(\tilde{T}) = range(T)$. Thus, it will follow that $V/ \ker T$ is isomorphic to $range(T)$.